# JS Performance -- hash two numbers, avoid Array creation

Tags: javascript, performance, hashmap, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I need the most efficient way to both recreate and read values in this hash map

> **All numbers will be positive**, if that helps for **hashing / bit shift** sake
>
> `myArray[someX][someY][someHeight && someWidth]`
>
> Could I use **someX** and **someY** since theyre unique and known?

I'm going to be storing to and reading from this array millions of times and need to run comparisons using **someHeight** and **someWidth**

I don't want to create a collection (Array or Object) to store just two numbers, since I'm also rewriting this data structure and I think I can get away without thousands of arrays. I also need an inexpensive way to split them apart.

Could someone shed light on the performance of 1) accessing a variable, 2) Array vs primitive creation, and 3) speed of relevent mathematical operations (bitwise)

The point of this data structure is for me to access random locations and run millions of comparisons with other points

but I'm not sure how to use basic Math or bitwise shifting operations to uniquely store the two together

Thanks

Bonus points if you can store all numeric values as one, instead of using Arrays of Arrays

Comment: You generally can’t split a hash back apart. Hashes aren’t unique. Why not try with the most straightforward structure and measure its performance?

Comment: Pretty much, is there any bitwise / mathematical equation that can bidirectionally hash them together?

Comment: @minitech You are right, I added a comment about all values should be positive too, but yea hashes are generally 1 directional

Comment: `y * (maxX + 1) + x`, invert to `y = hash / (maxX + 1) | 0` and `x = hash % (maxX + 1)`, for one. That only works if `maxY * (maxX + 1)` fits in 32 bits, though, and again, it may not have any advantage over using the obvious nested structure. You really do need to benchmark.

Comment: Yea I heard division and multiplication are expensive, I wanna keep it linear or use shifting, would definitely need to benchmark with multiplication and division vs Array creation

Comment: @minitech could you write that as an answer, definitely deserves recognition

Answer (score 0):

> Bitwise is always faster on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/16-bit-shifting-vs-new-array)

---

For two integers between 0 and 65536 (16 bit):

- Shift first number 16 slots left (like a typewriter)
- Apply num2 bitmask to the now vacant right side (`000000000000000`)

---

```
var num1 = 1234,
    num2 = 5678;

var hash = (num1 << 16 | num2); // shift num1 left and paste num2

// shift right, num2 falls off
var retrievedNum1 = hash >>> 16;

// shift left, num1 falls off, shift right
var retrievedNum2 = hash << 16 >>> 16;
```